# Django ORM: add parent class and access its class variable from children

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I am working on a restaurant app (and new to Django/Python). I want to have a parent `class Dish` that will contain some counter or ID that increments for every instance of a child class of `Dish`. The instances are dishes like Pizza, Pasta, etc with different characteristics. I've tried making `Dish` abstract and non-abstract, but come across different issues each time.

This is my Dish class (to make it abstract I tried InheritanceManager(), but ran into complications there that led me to think it's overkill for my simple purposes. Non-abstract, kept giving me `You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'pasta_ptr'`, followd by `IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed`):

```
class Dish(models.Model):
  #objects = InheritanceManager()
  counter = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

  class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

This is an example of a child class - I'd like every pasta-entry to get its own Dish-ID or counter on the menu - like a class attribute in Python. How do I access and implement this from the child class? If `Dish` is not abstract, can I use (& access) Dish's primary key that will tie each dish to my desired ID?

```
class Pasta(Dish):
  #Dish.counter +=1
  name = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name}, price: ${self.price}"
```

Comment: what is your intention on doing so?  Can you clarify what is your database should look like?

Comment: At this stage it should display a bunch of menu items (dishes) on an html page. But I need each dish to have a unique ID, hence storing this ID/counter attribut in parent class. The reason I need this ID, is so I can give html-ID attributes to the input forms later.

Comment: so Pasta, Pizza and etc.  each is  a new dish, right? Self implementing. auto increment id is not suggestible. I would suggest reconsidering your approach or you can use uuid which will give 36 characters unique id

Comment: May I suggest your design is wrong ?  You should only have one (concrete) `Dish` model, and (if needed) use FKs or m2ms to related models for the parts that change (you can use a `DishType` model to distinguish pizzas from pastas for your listings for example), plus perhaps (and still if needed) proxy models if you have different behaviours. wrt/ unique ids, django will automagically create a unique (per table) auto PK if you don't provide one, so you really have nothing special to do (when using a single concrete `Dish` model that is...).

Comment: Thanks to both of you. The problem is that some dishes and their behaviours are complicated (# of toppings, price, size categories etc), others just have 1 name & price. If I make my ```Dish``` model concrete, I'd agree and say I can just access the auto-generated PK. But how do I access the ```Dish```'s PK out of the child (Pasta or so)?