# Django ORM Inheritance: You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'dish_ptr' to [...] without a default

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I am working on a restaurant app (and new to Django/Python). I want to have a parent class Dish that will contain some counter or ID that increments for every instance of a child class of Dish. The instances are dishes like Pizza, Pasta, etc with different characteristics and relations. I'm trying to make `Dish` concrete, because in that case I reckon I just access `Dish`'s PK and that will give each menu-item a Dish-ID. 
However, I don't know how to correctly fix the errors I come across: `You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'pasta_ptr'`.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
class Dish(models.Model):
  pass # should automatically generate PK, right?

class Pasta(Dish):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name}, price: ${self.price}"

class Pizza(Dish):
  sizestyle = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=SIZESTYLE_CHOICES, default=SMALL_REGULAR)
  topping_count = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(5), MinValueValidator(0)])
  price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

  def __str__(self):
    return f"Price for {self.sizestyle} pizza with {self.topping_count} toppings: ${self.price}"

class Sub(Dish):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)
  price_category = models.ForeignKey(SubPrice, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="sub_price_category")

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name}, Price Category: {self.price_category}"

class Platter(Dish):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)
  price_large = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
  price_small = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.name} price: Large ${self.price_large}, Small ${self.price_small}"
```

Comment: If you already have Pastas or Pizzas in your database, they need to know which concrete Dish to associate with. If you have no important data yet, drop the db or `python manage.py migrate dish_app zero` and delete and remake the migrations.

Comment: As I already [commented on your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948986/), your design is wrong.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks. I think the part where you suggest just using ```DishType``` model to distinguish Pasta from Pizza doesn't work given the above? But the part about using FK to link the pizzas, etc to ```Dish``` as a dish-ID FK would mean only adding that 1 line for each child and would do the trick? (sorry - I am new to this, don't know what proxy models are, etc)

Comment: @Anna your design issue is that you're doing a one-to-one mapping of each kind of dish to a particular model - you're trying to directly translate the user's view of your data to the db schema - instead of doing a more in-depth analysis and designing a schema that can describe all kinds of dishes (existing and to come) into an uniform schema. This schema can of course not be a simple mapping of how the users (end users and site admins) view the data, and some intermediary domain layer will be needed to translate the db schema into domain objects, but that's the case with most non-trivial app.

Comment: As an example: your "Platter" class has two price fields for small and large portions. This in fact means that a dish can have one or many prices, so you should have a "Price" entity with a "qualifier" (ie "small", "large", etc) and a FK on the "Dish" entity. With this approach, when the restaurant decides to add a "medium" or a "king size" portion they just have to configure it in the backend.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers, thank you for the detail & example. The problem is that e.g. dishes have few common characteristics: Pizza doesn't have a name, Prices for pizza are a calculation based on # of toppings - the "Price" entity (I assume you mean model?) and a qualifier would probably not work for pizza...?

Comment: "Pizza doesn't have a name" => the make the dish name optional, or just name the dish "pizza". "Prices for pizza are a calculation based on # of toppings" => then you need one additional level of indirection - for example a "Pricer" object ([strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)) that knows how to compute a dish's price (I have the very same case in my current app and that's how I implemented the solution).  Note that I'm not saying your current design will not work at all, nor that the approach I suggest is "simpler" (it's actually more complex indeed) ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers  - much appreciated! I'll give my dish & dishtype design another go. Your approach is defo 'better design'. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wanted to inherit from `Dish()` but not have it in the database, you could do this:  [Django abstract base class docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    # your model structure

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Pizza(Dish):
    # your model structure
```

This would just inherit whatever is in Dish when you use it. You will not see Dish as a table in the database.

If you do want to use it as a parent class, you need to tell the subclasses that Dish is a parent class: [django many to one docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#many-to-one-relationships)

```
class Dish(models.Model):
    pass

class Pizza(models.Model):
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # other model structure
```

This would create an id for Dish in the database and when Pizza is created, it would reference the id (pk) of Dish.

Comment: thank you. I tried the latter but get ```Reverse query name for 'Pizza.dish' clashes with reverse query name for 'Pizza.dish_ptr'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Pizza.dish' or 'Pizza.dish_ptr'``` - so I added a related name. But when running makemigrations again, I get again ```You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'dish' to pasta without a default```. Why would it require a default value if it refers to an auto-generated PK in ```Dish```?

Comment: The reason you are getting that last error is because you are right a `pk` is a non-nullable field.  That means that you have data in the database that is already represented by `dish_ptr`, so when you run migrations Django has no idea that Dish was a primary key to Pizza before adding `dish = models.ForeignKey...`.  The only way I currently know how to fix this, is to remove the data in the database then run migrations.  I took your models, ran migrations, added data, then updated the models to my example, and had to remove the data in order to get a successful migration.

Comment: you can always salvage the data by running `python manage.py dumpdata -o path/to/output/file.json` but before you run `python manage.py loaddata path/to/file.json` you will need to do some editing in the json file or you would get another error, because of the `dish_ptr` reference in the file.